# How to show li class that is the same with the clicked li in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have dynamic list in WordPres and each `<li>` has a class. I have no control of the content inside `class="woof_list woof_list_radio"` because it is generated by a plugin.

```
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

    <li class="woof_term_224">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 1</label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="woof_term_225">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 2</label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="woof_term_226">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 3</label>
    </li>

</ul>

<br>

<ul class="banner-info-list">

    <li class="woof_term_224" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 1</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 1</span>
    </li>

    <li class="woof_term_225" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 2</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 2</span>
    </li>

    <li class="woof_term_226" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 3</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 3</span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I want to show one of the `<li>` inside class="banner-info-list" to whatever `<li>` was clicked inside `class="woof_list woof_list_radio"`

For example: If I click Parent 1 `<label>`, I want to show the content of

```
<li class="woof_term_226" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 3</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 3</span>
 </li>
```

because they have the same class that is equal to **woof_term_226**

This is my current jquery code but it is not yet complete:

```
j('.woof_list_radio .woof_radio_label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstClass =  j(this).attr('class');

    console.log(firstClass);
    j(firstClass).show('slow').siblings().hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: or even `j('.banner-info-list > li.'+firstClass`)

Comment: You'll want to select the parent class though, otherwise `firstClass` is `woof_radio_label`

Comment: This is true - so `var firstClass = j(this).closest('li').attr('class');`

Comment: @Stender can your write your comment as answer, your answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the class name attribute on each click, and use it on `.banner-info-list` selector to find the li you need to show:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".woof_list_radio .woof_radio_label", function() {
    var classAttr = $(this).closest("li").attr("class")
    $(".banner-info-list li[class^='woof_term_']").hide()
    $(".banner-info-list").find("."+classAttr).show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

    <li class="woof_term_224">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 1</label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="woof_term_225">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 2</label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="woof_term_226">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 3</label>
    </li>

</ul>

<br>

<ul class="banner-info-list">

    <li class="woof_term_224" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 1</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 1</span>
    </li>

    <li class="woof_term_225" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 2</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 2</span>
    </li>

    <li class="woof_term_226" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="et_pb_module_header">Title 3</h1>
        <span class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_subhead">Content 3</span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you guru. Nice to see you used .on for dynamic elements generated by ajax

Comment: @ConanCarroll  Damn - cleaner answer - deserves the accept.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the parent class, and at the same time, you should only show the li.whateverClass in the banner-info.

Sp you jQuery could be done like this :

```
j('.woof_list_radio .woof_radio_label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Getting the parent class
    var firstClass = j(this).closest('li').attr('class');

    console.log(firstClass);
    //Showing the correct li
    j('.banner-info-list > li.'+firstClass).show('slow').siblings().hide('slow');
});
```